# Will the following two ways cause running out of heap space?

Tags: java, scala

as suggested to be a new question about running out of space:

I learned to write Scala programs three months ago. I doubt my ways of writing the program causes the heap space, so following are some points to check if I may:

- suppose I'm building a graph, with nodes and edges. The "graph" is
  one parameter to a function. The function will explore the passed in
  graph, and expand graph to a new one. Then the new graph will be
  passed again and recursively calls the function to re-explore, until
  some conditions are reached, the final version of the graph will be
  returned.

So in this case, if the graph along the way is growing and growing, will it cause out of heap?

- If this is bad practice, how should I write it memory efficiently?

There is an object used to store all static information, Will it cause the problem?

Comment: It depends on how much the graph grows.

Comment: Every ever-growing data structure will eventually eat up the memory. Could you provide some code - I'm finding it hard to get around this "function"...

Comment: Depends on how it expands the graph to a new one and how the graph grows (actual memory it takes vs max memory available for your process).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So in this case, if the graph along the way is growing and growing, will it cause out of heap?

It would depend on how much the graph grows. At some point if you just keep adding nodes then it will run out of heap space.

Practically though you will most likely run out of heap because of a bug and miss the end condition and end of in an infinite loop.

If you were creating multiple copies of the graph -- i.e. if every recutsion created a new deep copy and held on to it while it called itself recursively -- then you will run out of memory much sooner.

Comment: if it ends infinite loop but not adding any new stuff to the graph, will it still run out of heap? and, in Scala, is the parameter deep copied?

Comment: If it is an infinite loop then it will likely run out of `Stack`, not heap. From what little I know of Scala, a tree parameter such as this cannot be deep copies when passed to a method.

Comment: @MiserableVariable - It wouldn't be deep-copied by default.  "Cannot" is too strong; it depends on what you do.  Write a recursive method with `+` when you meant `+=` and you very well could....

Comment: @RexKerr I am not an expert on Scala, but given that the Graph class seems to be user defined, how can any calling convention know how to make a deep copy, short of the called method itself creating it?

Comment: @MiserableVariable: The concept of a "persistent data structure" (nothing to do with serialization) is that when you create a variation on an immutable value the new value shares as much as possible of the original value. There's a substantial literature on persistent data structures, though it's generally only known of in the functional programming community.

Comment: @MiserableVariable - The called method can intend to do an _update_ but actually end up _creating an entirely new copy_.  This sort of error wouldn't happen often, and it would only happen in recursive code (that's where the deepness comes from), but it is possible to intend one thing and with a relatively minor syntax change (and some unfortunate choices of what is marked `val` and `var`) get the other.

Comment: @RexKerr if old graph represented as `(nodes, edges)`, then my new graph that is to be passed as parameter is `(newNodes, newEdges)`  where `val newNodes = nodes++ ns, val newEdges = edges++ nes`,  will this cause problem?

Comment: @RexKerr you should add an answer with this explanation so I can delete my answer.

Comment: @monica - What data structures are `nodes` and `edges`, and do you hold on to the old graph anywhere (e.g. in the recursion)?

Comment: I'm not sure yet that my guess is the correct answer.  Depends what Monica says about the data structures.

Comment: @RexKerr The data structures for `nodes` and `edges` are all `Set`. and in the recursion, I get ahold of old nodes and edges, somehow get new ones `ns`, `nes`. I'm not sure how exactly you mean `hold on to the old graph`...

Comment: @monica perhaps you should update the question with more code, showing declarations etc

Comment: @monica - `collection.mutable.Set` or `collection.immutable.Set`?  (Or the default `Set`?)

Comment: @RexKerr I tried my best to use immutable data structure, so it is `scala.collection.immutable.Set`

Comment: @monica - Well, then that ought not be the problem; you'd run out of stack space first most likely.  Adding elements to a set is effectively constant memory usage (i.e. linear in the number of elements), as long as you put the old set on the left of the `++`.  I guess it's some other bug, and MiserableVariable's answer is as close to one as I could provide.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using the [Graph for Scala](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-graph/wiki) library? It will give you a considerable leg up on the graph representation part of your project. You can find its [PDF documents here](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-graph/documents).